# Add a number to every element of a vector of generic types

Tags: rust

In the process of learning Rust, I'm trying to add an integer to every element of a vector:

```
trait Arith: Copy {
    fn add(self, b: Self) -> Self;
    fn mult(self, b: Self) -> Self;
    fn print(self);
}

impl Arith for i32 {
    fn add(self, b: Self) -> Self {
        self + b
    }

    fn mult(self, b: Self) -> Self {
        self * b
    }

    fn print(self) {
        println!("Val = {}", self);
    }
}

fn vec_add<T: Arith>(vec: &mut Vec<T>) {
    for e in vec.iter_mut(){
        /* e is of type &mut i32. But you can give it to print() which
           expects i32 because rust derefs it implicitly */
        e.print();
        e.add(5);
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello World");
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    vec_add(&mut vec);
}
```

But I'm facing the following issue:

```
<anon>:33:15: 33:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `T`,
    found `_`
(expected type parameter,
    found integral variable) [E0308]
<anon>:33         e.add(5);
```

Can you please explain what mistake I'm making here?

Comment: Note: you do realize that `e.add(5)` returns `e + 5` but does not modify `e` itself, right?

Comment: Yup. I changed it to *e = e.add(5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number 5 is a integer (I think it's `i32` by default or maybe `u32`, at the moment I don't remember). The type `T`, which is the generic type, can be anything so in general 5 is not of the same type of `T`. You can force `T` to be an integer or you could change `vec_add` this way:

```
fn vec_add<T: Arith>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, val: T){
    for e in vec.iter_mut(){
        /* e is of type &mut i32. But you can give it to print() which
           expects i32 because rust derefs it implicitly */
        e.print();
        e.add(val);
    }
}

fn main(){
    println!("Hello World");
    let mut vec: Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    vec_add(&mut vec, 5);
}
```

Comment: So in `fn add(self, b: Self) -> Self`, `Self` is of type `T` in `vec_add` context?